# Check if user has access on site using client object model

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model

Need to check if any user (provided user name) has access to site using c# client object model. It is sharepoint online site.

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See answers [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/129309/20615).  They work for sites as well as lists.