# user permissions on document in sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Is there any way to get the data of users permission on sharepoint site's  documents  and how to get list of users permission on a file or document in sharepoint by powershell or other thing ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: please refer this
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129309/how-to-get-permission-of-a-sharepoint-list-for-a-user-using-rest-api#answer-130563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you can get the permissions on the document library and see the groups who got access and what permission level they have. (this is from document library settings --> permissions). However, I believe you mean to know the item/document level, and this can be done by right click on each document and check the Shared With option, but if you want to see a list of all documents and who has access and who has not, then a more complex solution / script can be created to do that. However, I came across Sharegate new security and management tool that does that very well (but sharegate is not free)

Comment: thank you  is sharegate work for sharepoint online or on premises ?

Comment: works for both. In my last project, I used it for very similar requirements on O365. One more thing, Sharegate also tracks external users (if you ever want to know if a document was shared externally and what permission level is given)

Comment: glad this helped! Please mark this as an answer if you believe it answered your question