# Create list from sharepoint workflow?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, permissions

I have two queries:-

- Can we create a **List** from **SharePoint Designer workflow**? I can't see any action for creating list.
- Can we break the **permission** of list and provide custom permission through **SharePoint Designer**?

Comment: Nintex is off topic, I cleaned it up as it still has value without that aspect.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired outcome through web services. So basically you have to use call web service actions from your workflow.

In your case you can use

1. Add method of `http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` web service to create the list based on a particular template. See this [url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlist(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.
2. For modifying permissions you have to use permissions web service at `http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Permissions.asmx` there multiple methods which might be useful in your case based on what you want to do. If I were you I would look at documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/permissions.permissions_methods(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot create list from SharePoint workflow. But you can achieve this using web services like **Rest API**, **JSOM**, **CSOM** etc.
2. **SharePoint designer** will redirect you to the list permission editor web-page. Then you can set custom permissions. You can also achieve this using the web services mentioned above using in SharePoint designer.

Here I am mentioning some links those can help you doing this with **Rest API**:

- [Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 REST endpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)
- [REST API reference and samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)
- [Set custom permissions on a list by using the REST interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495392.aspx)
- [How to get permission of a sharepoint list for a user using REST api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129309/how-to-get-permission-of-a-sharepoint-list-for-a-user-using-rest-api)