# How to check whether the current user has edit permission for a particular list using JSOM in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, jsom, sharepoint-list, check-permissions

I have created a Custom list named **Test List**. I need to check whether the current user is having edit list permission for **Test List** list or not, by using JSOM.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try using below code. Since its OnPrem, we first need to get the login name of user and pass it to the `get_effectiveBasePermissions` method.

To ensure that user has edit permission, we will check the `SP.PermissionKind.editListItems` enum.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
    getCurrentUserPermission();
});


function getCurrentUserPermission()
{    
    var web,clientContext,currentUser,oList,perMask;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();   
    oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Test List');
    clientContext.load(oList,'EffectiveBasePermissions');
    clientContext.load(currentUser); 
    clientContext.load(web);           

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        if (oList.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems)){
            console.log("user has edit permission");
        }else{
             console.log("user doesn't have edit permission");
        }   
    }, function(sender, args){
        console.log('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is the code you are looking for:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();

var ob = new SP.BasePermissions();
ob.set(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb)
ob.set(SP.PermissionKind.managePermissions)

var per = web.doesUserHavePermissions(ob)
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){ 
          alert(per.get_value()); // If this is true, user has permission, if not, no 
        },
     function(a,b){
         alert ("Something wrong");
 }
);
```

Instead of `web` you can check for `list`.

Found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678653/How-to-check-user-permission-for-the-web-list-or-S).

You can also get complete list of permission enumeration [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556747(v=office.14).aspx).

If you want to do this via REST API, then references are [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/129311/30145) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj245877.aspx) for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but  I need to check whether the current user is having edit list permission for **Test List**