# Hide the Approve/Reject button in AllItems.aspx in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, css, approval-process

I would like to hide the menu item in a document library that reads "Approve/Reject":
[image]

Since approval is being managed by a workflow that I created. Most online articles tell the solution to this issue is adding custom CSS to the page so I am trying this method. I have opened the page `~/AllItems.aspx` in SharePoint Designer.

Upon inspecting the HTML for the page in my browser, I found the html for that button:

[image]

I tried editing `AllItems.aspx` as follows but the button would not disappear:

[image]

Can someone please give a **full**, *working explanation* of how I might achieve hiding this button?

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` in your css like `display: none !important;`?

Comment: No, I am unsure if I am even editing the correct file. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot where exactly these buttons are?

Comment: please see the updated question @LittSpector

Comment: check out my answer, it should solve ur issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo in that css. Either try

```
<style type="text/css">
 button[name="Approve/Reject"] > div > span {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
 button[name="Approve/Reject"] span {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

The reason why your css rule doesnt work is because you are targeting `span` right under the next sibling level of a `button` element, but the `span` shown in your html example is nested under a deeper level.

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you.

Comment: As a bonus.... do you know if I can enable or disable this CSS depending on user permission level?

Comment: Sure I can do that. Please edit your post so you include that question and also mention which environment you are working on, thanks

Comment: btw @JoshSharkey, if the code provided solves your issue, It would be nice to mark my post as an answer so I could redeem the bounty, thanks

Comment: I will reward the bounty now, after I can verify the functionality I will mark the answer as corrected.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Regarding ur last question, you can implemente this method https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219852/how-to-check-whether-the-current-user-has-edit-permission-for-a-particular-list and then add some styling with javascript based on the resutls ,